# How to declare string of fixed size length in c++?

Tags: c++, string, c++14

I wanted to declare a variable of size 'N'. Further a string of fixed length 'N'.
Also, how can I give value to that string on run-time?

like, I tried for
cin>>N;
string str(4);

no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string::basic_string(int)'

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no constructor in `std::string` that only takes a size parameter. You also need to provide a `char` value that will be used as the initial value of every character in the string. To have a string of `N` spaces for example, you'd do:

```
std::string str(N, ' ');
```

However, the string will not be fixed size. You can still change its length later on:

```
str += ' '; // Now it contains N + 1 spaces.
```

You can't have a fixed size `std::string` unless you make it `const`. But if you do that, then you can't change the contents of the string anymore.